# What is the correct MySql FULL JOIN syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Following are my two tables; I want the results as illustrated in the third table. How can I do this in MySQL (assuming FULL JOIN)?

**table_sales**

```
product_id    quantity    date
c001          20        2013-09-03
t008          30        2013-09-01
t008          20        2013-09-03
c001          90        2013-09-09
```

**table_returns**

```
product_id    quantity    date
t008          40        2013-09-08
t008          30        2013-09-01
c001          10        2013-09-03
```

I want to get result like:

```
product_id     sale_qty      return_qty        date
c001           20            10              2013-09-03
c001           90            -               2013-09-09
t008           30            30              2013-09-01
t008           20            -               2013-09-01
t008           -             40              2013-09-08
```

Comment: Yep, that’s a FULL JOIN — are you asking what the syntax is? Or how to alias things? Or…?

Comment: This has been asked before, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql

Comment: @Alexander I can't found answer what i want so I give this post

Comment: You could always upgrade to Postgres ;) (SCNR)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My preferred method for doing a `full join` is to get the list of all ids and the `left join` to that list:

```
select driver.product_id, s.quantity as sale_qty, r.quantity as return_qty, driver.date
from (select product_id, date from table_sales
      union 
      select product_id, date from table_returns
     ) driver left join
     table_sales s
     on driver.product_id = s.product_id and driver.date = s.date left join
     table_returns r
     on driver.product_id = r.product_id and driver.date = r.date;
```

I find that putting the `union` in the `from` clause makes the query more convenient.  Logic about handling the variables, formulas, and joins only have to be included once.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ba31a/3) is the SQL Fiddle that demonstrates that it works.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL lacks support for FULL OUTER JOIN.

So if you want to emulate a Full join on MySQL take a look [here](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/06/emulating-full-outer-join-in-mysql/) .

This is a very helpfull link, describing the workaround for full join

sample workaround will be like

```
SELECT  t_13.value AS val13, t_17.value AS val17
FROM    t_13
LEFT JOIN
t_17
ON      t_13.value = t_17.value
UNION ALL
SELECT  t_13.value AS val13, t_17.value AS val17
FROM    t_13
RIGHT JOIN
t_17
ON      t_13.value = t_17.value
WHERE   t_13.value IS NULL
ORDER BY
COALESCE(val13, val17)
LIMIT 30
```